# How we exclude current post form related posts

Tags: posts

When user open any post, then on the right side they can see related `posts` to that post. But currently in related `posts` my current open post also showing, how i can `exclude` that post which is currently open.

Answer (score 3):

Use the parameter `'post__not_in'` to exclude post IDs:

```
$posts = new WP_Query(
    array (
        'post__not_in' => array(get_the_ID()) // exclude current post ID
    )
);
```

Comment: Use the source in a plugin, about the hook `pre_get_posts` is sure the best way.

Answer (score 1):

If you could give us some code snippets of what you are currently using, it would help us formulate an answer. Unfortunately I don't have enough reputation to say this as a comment on the OP, so I will provide my answer based on the knowledge provided in the OP.

When loading the current post (presumably by using `single.php`), you can save the post ID in a PHP variable, like so:

```
<?php $do_not_duplicate = $post->ID; ?>
```

Later, in your loop to display related posts, you need an if-statement to skip the loop if the ID's match. Like so:

```
<?php
    // Get related posts
    $related = new WP_Query( $args );
    while ( $related->have_posts() ) : $related->the_post();
        if (in_array($post->ID, $do_not_duplicate)) continue;
?>
<!-- Your html for related post listing -->
<?php 
    endwhile;           // End 'while have_posts()'
    wp_reset_postdata();    // Reset Post Data
?>
```

Comment: `<?php
$args=array(
'category_name' => $catname,
'post_type' => 'post',
 'post_status' => 'publish',
'posts_per_page' => 12,
'caller_get_posts'=> 1
);
       $my_query = null;
$my_query = new WP_Query($args);
if( $my_query->have_posts() ) { 
while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post();

?>`

Comment: @Adi Please(!) **always** _update/edit_ your question with additional information. Don't write comments for that. A comment should be "Hey, I added the info :)" or similar.

Comment: @MarcDingena If you need clarification of the question, please leave a comment at the question requesting additional Info. Thanks.

Comment: @kaiser next time i be carefull about that. But i want to know one thing how i make my code in a block. The short code provide is not working in my comments. See my above commment how it look.

Comment: @kaiser I can't do that because I don't have 50 reputation yet.

Comment: @Adi As I said: Don't put code in comments. It's not supposed to be there. Edit/Update your question with it. There simply are no code blocks in comments for a reason.